# How to position only part of the content at the top right of the td?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a table and within the `td` I have an `a` tag with `class='day'`.  I want the `class='day'` to be at the top right of the `td`. I thought this should be as simple as setting the following css:

```
td { position: relative;} 
.day{ position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

That's not working right. I have the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mftp7/

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not come up against this before, but it looks like a quirk of `td` elements being `display:table-cell` by default, which don't seem to listen properly to relative positioning.

As a workaround, you could wrap the contents of your `td` inside a `div` and make the `div` relative instead. Then you'll get the desired behaviour.

Comment: worked great - just added a div with the class td and rearranged the css to match. that's a really annoying little quirk!

Answer (score 4):

`table` elements can not be *reliably* positioned.

A way around this would be to wrap the `a` within another element have it `position: relative`.

See it in action for the first day of the month - http://jsfiddle.net/Mftp7/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
td { 
    vertical-align: top; 
    text-align: right;
}
```

for all text in top right.

Comment: That will align the numbers as well as events in the top right

Answer (score 0):

Positioning is tricky with tables.  Instead of using positioning, use `vertical-align: top;` on the table cells, and put the day inside a block level element so that you can put `text-align: right` on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mftp7/6/

```
<td><p class="day"><a href="#">6</a></p></td>

table.calendar td, table.calendar th
  { vertical-align: top; }
p.day
{ text-align: right; }
```